# Terminology question, maximum on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

If we have a function $x^2$, is there a maximum on the open interval $(-1,1)$?

What does maximum in this context mean?  Does it mean that we narrow the interval and thus there is a maximum on the open interval $(-1,1)$?

Or does it mean that we still have the function $\text{real numbers} \rightarrow \text{real numbers}$ and there is no maximum on that open interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in(-1,1)$, then $x^2\in[0,1)$.

The interval $[0,1),$ a subset of $\mathbb R$, has a [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) (namely, $1$), but no [maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima).